# Concatenate masked inputs in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

Using the Keras API, I am trying to construct a neural net model as follows. I have two inputs which are each categorical time series which have been converted to one-hots. Within a batch, the time series are generally of different lengths, so I have padded them with zeros out to a common length. I would like to first apply a Masking layer to each input in order to ignore the paddings, then apply TimeDistributed Dense layers to each, and finally concatenate the outputs of the Dense layers before passing the result into an LSTM. (It's not important, a final linear Dense layer is applied after the LSTM.) Something like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input,Dense,Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.layers import TimeDistributed,LSTM,Masking
from tensorflow.keras import Model

input1=Input(shape=(None,5),batch_size=batch_size) #five categories for feature 1
input2=Input(shape=(None,3),batch_size=batch_size) # three categories for feature 2
masked1=Masking(mask_value=0,input_shape=(None, 5))(input1)
masked2=Masking(mask_value=0,input_shape=(None, 3))(input2)
dense1=TimeDistributed(Dense(16,activation='relu'))(masked1)
dense2=TimeDistributed(Dense(16,activation='relu'))(masked2)
concat=TimeDistributed(Concatenate(axis=-1))([dense1,dense2])
lstm=LSTM(512,activation='tanh',return_sequences=True,stateful=False)(concat)
out=TimeDistributed(Dense(5,activation='linear'))(lstm)
model=Model(inputs=[input1,input2],outputs=out)
```

However, concatenating masked inputs doesn't appear to work in Keras; the line with the Concatenate layer gives rise to the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'`.

Can anyone suggest a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do or something similar?

Comment: I think you don't need timedistributed layer wrapper for concatenate layer.

Comment: wow, that actually fixed the issue lol

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> ```
> from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input,Dense,Concatenate
> from tensorflow.keras.layers import TimeDistributed,LSTM,Masking
> from tensorflow.keras import Model
>
> input1=Input(shape=(None,5),batch_size=batch_size) #five categories for feature 1
> input2=Input(shape=(None,3),batch_size=batch_size) # three categories for feature 2
> masked1=Masking(mask_value=0,input_shape=(None, 5))(input1)
> masked2=Masking(mask_value=0,input_shape=(None, 3))(input2)
> dense1=TimeDistributed(Dense(16,activation='relu'))(masked1)
> dense2=TimeDistributed(Dense(16,activation='relu'))(masked2)
> concat=Concatenate(axis=-1)([dense1,dense2])
> lstm=LSTM(512,activation='tanh',return_sequences=True,stateful=False)(concat)
> out=Dense(5,activation='linear')(lstm)
> model=Model(inputs=[input1,input2],outputs=out)
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> Model: "model"
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
> ==================================================================================================
> input_1 (InputLayer)            [(32, None, 5)]      0                                            
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> input_2 (InputLayer)            [(32, None, 3)]      0                                            
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> masking (Masking)               (32, None, 5)        0           input_1[0][0]                    
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> masking_1 (Masking)             (32, None, 3)        0           input_2[0][0]                    
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> time_distributed (TimeDistribut (32, None, 16)       96          masking[0][0]                    
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> time_distributed_1 (TimeDistrib (32, None, 16)       64          masking_1[0][0]                  
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> concatenate (Concatenate)       (32, None, 32)       0           time_distributed[0][0]           
>                                                                  time_distributed_1[0][0]         
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> lstm (LSTM)                     (32, None, 512)      1116160     concatenate[0][0]                
> __________________________________________________________________________________________________
> dense_2 (Dense)                 (32, None, 5)        2565        lstm[0][0]                       
> ==================================================================================================
> Total params: 1,118,885
> Trainable params: 1,118,885
> Non-trainable params: 0
> _____________________________________________________________________________
> ```
>
> (paraphrased from Kaveh)